# After exec(), child inherits file descriptors but streams may be inaccessible?

Tags: c, exec

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdout.3.html

[image]

What does the statement "but all old streams have become inaccessible" mean? From my current understanding, all inherited handles should still be usable. Is my understanding incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File descriptors are just integers that are managed by the operating system.  They are unaffected by `exec`.  Streams (i.e., `FILE *`), on the other hand, are collections of buffers and state information managed by a library.  They act as a layer above file descriptors.  When `exec` is called, all of the buffers and state information associated with a stream are wiped out when the new image is loaded.  They're just gone.  Any pending buffered data or state info is lost.

Comment: so the buffers in my `some_handle` are lost. but I can still print to it if I want.  So its not so much "inaccessible" as "wiped the hell out". Right?

Comment: You can read from/write to the underlying file descriptor, assuming you know what it is, yes.  The main point is you don't want to have any buffered data when you do the `exec` since it will be lost. It's cleanest to have no open streams at the time of the `exec`.

Comment: Output streams can be `fflush`ed before you do the `exec` to output any buffered data, but you cannot "unread" anything that has been buffered on any input streams before you do the `exec`.

Answer (score 2):

I think "old stream" means "FILE *" structure.

After an exec, all stream (FILE *) open with fopen will be close and all file descriptor (int) will be inherited.
You can change the inherite behavior for file descriptor by adding the FD_CLOEXEC to them.

Comment: b-but dont the structs wrap around the descriptors? arent they practically the same thing? can you give an example of what I can/cant do in this scenario in C?

Comment: You can't open a file with "fopen", do an exec and expect that the program executed by "exec" will use your FILE * previously opened.
On the other hand, you can create a socket, bind it to a specific port/interface, do an exec and watch your socket is still connected.
That's why you can add option to file descriptor for closing file descriptor after an exec.

Comment: Lets say I am retarded. Why exactly do the structs not get transfered along with everything else. I get the vague sense its because of "my libraries" different from low level IO, but what. Is it some esoteric implementation detail that completely crumbles at the sight of exec or something?

Comment: Sorry, i can't explain you in detail why this behavior happens, but if I have to guess, I will say exactly like Tom Karzes, plus I supose all file descriptor open within a FILE* is opened with the FD_CLOEXEC option.
But I can't guaranted you that, it's only guess ... sorry.